# project reactor : non blocking , one producer , mutliple consumers

Tags: locking, project-reactor

In a event streaming application:
I have one thread reading from a queue  **writing** to another queue QA ( a Tree map non concurrent queue) -> (producer)
QA is  **accessed** by other threads -> (consumers) with a thread specific filter, these threads await for queue items if filtered QA is empty (long polling)

QA is also **reduced** (elements removed)  in a periodic manner ( so another thread).

All those **steps**  need to acquire a lock in order to be executed.

How can i avoid locking by using project reactor.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rewrite the whole thing to use the reactive pattern - which is a great thing and will improve your code.

Unfortunately as this is very different from the procedural approach, it will require you to take a few days / weeks and learn the basics of a reactive pipeline (or find somebody to do it for you). Reactive is not a thing you can start just like that.

This is a great starting point: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive

Comment: Thank for your response.    I am looking for a simple example , probably with sink and replay  with a limited history.